# Unit Testing Mac apps with Google Toolbox for MAC (GTM)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, macos, google-toolbox-for-mac

Is GTM only useful for iPhone apps or could I use it for both iPhone and Mac apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it for unit testing both OS X and iOS targets.